# not able to make entry of ubuntu 10.04 grub.cfg into redhat 5.1 menu.lst file to run 2 linux os and 1 windows

Tags: linux

In my computer there are three operating systems..

First i installed Windows 7 then i installed ubuntu 10.04

and in last i installed redhat 5.1

NOw i know one thing as i installed redhat then grub installed by ubuntu will be overwritten by redhat grub..and i know that to see all three operating syetm at the startup i have to make entry of /boot/grub/cfg into /boot/grub/menu.lst file..

**Now the problem is like this**

In te previous version it was very easy to play with ubuntu grub file but now this file is modified..NOw i dont know what is to be picked up from ubuntu /grub/grub.cfg file so that i can make entry in redhat /boot/grub/menu.lst file..

In short i am not able to put entry of grub.cfg file into redhat menu.lst file..
will u help me plz i want to work on these thre eOS..

Comment: is there any solution of this problem

Answer (score 1):

Recent releases of Ubuntu has been shipping with grub2 which uses different syntax for its configuration file from grub1 (which is what redhat uses, I believe).

If you have a look at the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file in ubuntu you should find a section which looks like this

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 5cf7c0d3-8b4d-428f-a54a-ea43ce486654
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=5cf7c0d3-8b4d-428f-a54a-ea43ce486654 ro quiet splash
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
}
```

which translates to following menu.lst entry

```
title Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic
root (hd0,3)
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=5cf7c0d3-8b4d-428f-a54a-ea43ce486654 ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
```

Of course, you will need to adjust disk UUIDs and partition numbers as per your configuration.

Comment: THe latest kernels won't boot on grub.  They require grub2.  You can configure grub to chain into grub2.